# TCPDF "Undefined index: cols" when using tables in view

Tags: cakephp-1.3, tcpdf

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 to make an online application system. I try to print a PDF document using TCPDF based on a view.

I use the code

```
$this->writeHTML($this->render('print') )
```

in my print controller.

The problem is that I have this

> undefined index : cols

error output to the screen. What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I run into the same problem today (even though I am not using CakePHP), and all it took to fix this problem was to add a valid `<thead>` element to every table that I was embedding. Apparently, TCPDF parses the `<thead>` element to determine the number of columns in a table when it outputs tables in PDF.

Also, I would recommend to generally check if your HTML is valid if some other errors keep occurring.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Your markup does need to be pretty valid for TCPDF to work correctly.

Comment: Had a similar issue. Only I needed to use '<br/>' instead of '</br>' for page breaks.

Comment: In my case i had unclosed `<strong>`. Like `<strong>Text<strong>`. After changing to `<strong>Text</strong>` all worked. But for example, if does not exist `</table>`, then worked without errors.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem, turns out one of my `<td>`'s wasn't closed.

Answer (score 3):

```
TCPDF “Undefined index: cols” when using tables in view
```

In some cases you may forget the closing tag or define the wrong tag, resulting in this error. This is because the tcpdf package does not allow wrong or incomplete html. 
I suggest that you should verify the code first.
You may be missing something in your html?

Otherwise swith to using simple html `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: This work properly

Answer (score 2):

This error showing in case you **missing close tag** (**any tag**), So check your code or you can use online tools like https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator

Answer (score 0):

It can be an open tag.

In my case I had `<span>text...<span>`